# Android Studio 2.1.2 - add library Cannot change dependencies of configuration?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-studio-2.1

I am adding library android-maps-utils to my project but get me bellow errors :

[image]

[image]

Comment: try using only include:'mylibraries'

Answer (score 0):

`File` > `Project Structure` > `app` (on the left panel) > `Dependencies` (on the top) > `+` (on the right) > `Module dependency` > select your module > `OK`